# awk extract part of string, compare to number, output original line intact

Tags: awk

using the basic awk tool, say I have a file, where there can be any number after "DP=" (in the 8th column) and before the semicolon.  I want to only keep lines where this number is > 10.

```
Chr1    26313   .       G       A,X     0       .       DP=78;I16=28,38,10,0,2405,88631,356,12836,3960,237600,530,29234,1195,26039,199,4509;VDB=0.0000  PL:DP   12,0,
Chr1    26597   .       G       T,X     0       .       DP=5;I16=29,27,0,10,2054,76598,389,15193,3360,201600,558,32130,1046,22598,238,5730;VDB=0.0000  PL:DP   48,0,
...etc..
```

How do I use awk to extract the number, and only return lines if the number is greater than 10?  My desired output would be (since in the other line, DP=5 is < 10 ):

```
Chr1    26313   .       G       A,X     0       .       DP=78;I16=28,38,10,0,2405,88631,356,12836,3960,237600,530,29234,1195,26039,199,4509;VDB=0.0000  PL:DP   12,0,
```

Here is what I have so far.. but I can't figure out how to extract the string and compare to a number:

```
awk '( $5 ~ /[ACGT]/ && $8 ~ /^DP=/  && $10 !~ /^0/) {print $0}'
```

Maybe I can split this into two awk commands?  Or maybe there is a trick to do this all in one call?

Sorry if it has been answered, but I looked around and couldn't figure it out..
I don't want to use perl, or gawk or anything else..

EDIT: I think I made my example too simple.. updated it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the field separator and test the condition. Adding 0 to the field gets rid of the trailing `;`

```
awk -F'=' '$2+0>10' file
```

Your sample input line appears to be a truncated version of your actual input. So keeping the rest of the conditions as is, you can just add the following check:

```
awk '$5~/[ACGT]/ && $8~/^DP=/ && $10!~/^0/{split($0,tmp,/[=;]/);if(tmp[2]>10) print}' file
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I made my example too simple and I'm not sure how to implement this with the other things I'm trying to do... advice?

Comment: added more detail, hopefully it makes more sense!

Comment: That works!  Actually I don't need the $8~/^DP=/ so I removed that. Very cool that split can be called inside awk.. def a nice approach!

Comment: @Paul Great news. Glad it worked out for you. Cheers!